# Sharelatex: a0poster class not working with Latex selected as my compiler

Tags: pdftex, sharelatex, psfrag, a0poster

I need to create an a0 poster, and I'd like to use the `a0poster` class. I'm editing my project on **Sharelatex** and I'm using `\psfrag` in my .tex file, so I'd like to use LaTeX as my compiler. However, when I try to compile my project, all I get is a blank page in the pdf viewer. If I switch do `pdfLatex`, I'm able to visualize the project, but `\psfrag` doesn't work. I tried to work this around by using the `auto-pst-pdf` package, but that didn't work either. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does ShareLaTeX produce a `.ps` file then or does it use `dvipdf` to transform the `LaTeX` generated `.dvi` to `.pdf` automatically?

Comment: It generates a .pdf file automatically, so I'm guessing it uses dvipdf as you mentioned.